# Arrow key problem with mathematica 12 and bash version 5

Tags: mathematical-optimization, command-line

I want to know if anyone experiences the issue with mathematica-12 with bash-5?

I am using the command line interface of mathematica. Now when I do up arrow or down arrow to go to history, it does not produce the previous commands rather

```
  ^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C^[[A
```

Now it does not happen with bash-4. Is there any way around?

My mathematica version is:

```
 Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
```

Bash version is:

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Of course bash-completion works normally in terminal, only while using mathematica it does not work.

Comment: look for `rlwrap` with your distro package manager

Comment: @Fortsaint, Well, I have installed that locally and after using `rlwrap math` I can see that it enables history. However usual `math` does not. I can of course redefine `math=rlwrap math`. But any other thoughts apart from this?

Comment: I do not know about Bash 5. I use bash 4..4.20 and Wolfram Engine 12, which include wolframscript. When I run `wolframscript` from the terminal I do no have that problem you mentioned. Try `wolframscript` instead of `math`

Comment: Unfortunately `wolframscript` also shows same behavior as `math`. I also checked that it only appears with bash-5, In bash-4 I did not have any problem.

Comment: You can even have autocompletion with `rlwrap`.  Create the following text file  `Names["*"]~StringRiffle~"\n" // Export["WLNames.txt",#,"Text"]&`. Then create your custom version of `math` that execute `rlwrap -f  WLNames.txt  -pgreen wolframscript -c Dialog[]` . This is my custom `math` with some additional initialization functions https://github.com/Ludwiggle/math/blob/master/math
`

Comment: I have the same problem and using rlwrap did not fix anything. I have this problem with both bash 4.2.46 and 4.4.19. Same whether I use wolframscript or math.